# Google maps custom colors for UI

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to know if I can change the Google maps UI colour from blue to red.

I don't want to change the map colour but just the start/destination (Search box on the top) colour from blue to red. I will be using the Google Maps API

[image]

I have tried to find tutorial online but was unable to find any.

PS: I have never used Google API before

Comment: Are you looking to change the color of the entire map ?

Comment: You mean you want to change directly on Google Maps or you will use Google Maps API to create the new one?

Comment: I don't want to change the map colour but just the start/destination (Search box on the top) colour from blue to red. Yes i am creating an app using google map api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion regarding the directions API. When you use the API, you won't actually have the same directions UI that you see on maps.google.com. You have to build the UI part yourself and use the API to actually provide the directions. Users will use the UI you build to make the calls to the API. The API will then return directions for the requests sent.

There are two main options for directions, you can do client side directions using the directions service from the JavaScript API, or you can do server side directions using the directions web service. I believe the former will be more what you are looking for. Please see the documentation here:

Client Side directions using JavaScript API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Server side directions using directions web service:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start

There are also some good samples to show you what the directions service using the JavaScript API looks like. Please see here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-travel-modes
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

As you can see in the samples, you must build the UI yourself in order to use client side directions via the JS API. That being said you should be able to make the UI look however you want since you are the designer.

I hope this helps!